# xmodmap remapping doesn't work in java swing applications (like Intellij-IDEA)

Tags: linux, keyboard, java, keyboard-layout, intellij-idea

I created a `.Xmodmap` file to remap my `Caps_Lock` to `Mode_switch`. 
This allows me to reassign my Arrow/Navigation Block of the keyboard to the home row.

Everything worked fine, until I realized, that programs written on the java platform and use `Swing` (like Jetbrains' editors) don't recognize these remaps.

Now I want to port these settings to `xkb`, as it is deprecated to use `xmodmap`. 
(I think this could be the solution for this problem, but I really don't know how to make the same with xkb.) The `xkb` configuration is confusing to me, and seems like a really complicated approach for just this few remaps.

So, how can I do this?

I would really, prefer another approach/workaround for the java problem, so I could keep my xmodmap configuration.

Here is my `.Xmodmap` file:

```
! Disable Caps Lock and use it as mode switch
keycode 66 = Mode_switch Mode_switch

! Toggle Caps Lock with <Mode_switch> + <Control_R>
keysym Control_R = Control_R Control_R Caps_Lock

! Remap navigation block to ijkl...
keysym j = j J Left Left
keysym l = l L Right Right
keysym i = i I Up Up
keysym k = k K Down Down
keysym u = u U Home Home
keysym o = o O End End

! ö Ö
keycode 47 = odiaeresis Odiaeresis BackSpace BackSpace

keysym h = h H Delete Delete 
keysym n = n N Prior Prior

! enable mu for use with Iso_Level_3 (the right alt key on german keyboards)
keysym m = m M Next Next mu mu

! Space to Escape
keysym space = space space Escape
```

And here is my xmodmap output:

```
xmodmap:  up to 4 keys per modifier, (keycodes in parentheses):

shift       Shift_L (0x32),  Shift_R (0x3e)
lock        Mode_switch (0x42)
control     Control_L (0x25),  Control_R (0x69)
mod1        Alt_L (0x40),  Meta_L (0xcd)
mod2        Num_Lock (0x4d)
mod3      
mod4        Super_L (0x85),  Super_R (0x86),  Super_L (0xce),  Hyper_L (0xcf)
mod5        ISO_Level3_Shift (0x5c),  Mode_switch (0xcb)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was no way for me to make this work with `xmodmap` and fortunately I stumbled upon a guy who already made something similar with `xkb`.
Just follow this link and follow the instructions there to extend your keyboard layout with the "extend" layout, which maps `Caps_Lock` to `ISO_Level_5`.
http://forum.colemak.com/viewtopic.php?id=1438&p=1

Please read further in the forum to see how I solved a few little problems which bothered me. 
If your ttys and capslock is not working properly, look here: http://forum.colemak.com/viewtopic.php?id=1438&p=4.

Thanks to **Øystein Bech "DreymaR" Gadmar**, for making this possible!

Have fun!

Comment: I don't think a link to somewhere qualifies as an answer. Thanks though

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution to allow remapped keys using *xmodmap* such as your arrows in *pycharm*:

Use national layouts for shortcuts in Settings > Keymap

See this link: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-263057

Comment: Why the negative votes? Did I misunderstand something?

Comment: Well - I see a spam vote, which I rejected. Other than that, I assume that folks expect a more 'generic'answer